# How to remove 'maxlength' html attribute when using 'MaxLength' DataAnnotations attribute?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, unobtrusive-validation

I recently upgraded my web application from .NET Core 2.1 to Core 3.1.

Noticed that the unobtrusive validation of Max Length isn't working as before. There is html attribute **maxlength** being added to the **input** element. Because of this, user can put in only the max set number of characters in the input field. There is no message to inform the user that they have exceeded the max character limit of that particular field.

How do I notify user that they have reached/crossed the limit?

My code:

AddSpirit.cshtml

```
@model WebApp.ViewModels.SpiritViewModel

<div class="container pt-5">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <form asp-action="AddSpirit" method="POST">
                <fieldset class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Name"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Price"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Price" class="form-control" />
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Stock"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Stock" class="form-control" />
                </fieldset>

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger text-uppercase py-2 px-3 px-md-3 mb-2">  
                    Save Changes    
                </button>   
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial"); }
}
```

SpiritViewModel.cs

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace WebApp.ViewModels
{
    public class SpiritViewModel
    {
        [JsonProperty("name")]
        [MaxLength(5, ErrorMessage = "{0} should not be longer than {1} characters")]
        [MinLength(2, ErrorMessage = "{0} should be longer than {1} characters")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("price")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter the spirit's price.")]
        [Range(10, 500, ErrorMessage = "Accepting only spirits in price range INR 10 - 500")]
        public double Price { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("stock")]
        public int Stock { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting **maxlength** and **minlength** attribute values in cshtml would be a way to stop MaxLength or StringLength DataAnnotations limiting characters in the input field. Once the user is able to enter more characters, the unobtrusive validation works just fine.

```
<input asp-for="Name" maxlength="" minlength="" class="form-control" />
```